# ffmpeg multi convert videos and put them in the same path

Tags: conversion, ffmpeg, flv

I am using FFMPEG for converting from MOV to FLV on Ubuntu.

My problem is I have 10 folders and sub folders that contains those videos, I want a command line or a way in WinFF GUI to convert them all at ONCE not one by one and put them back in there folders so each conversion destination is the same as the video being converted.

Additionally I have a problem with the answer I have got is that it cannot convert videos not written in English or even if the path is not written in English such as Arabic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash (ie ubuntu) you would do

```
for file in $(cat filelist.txt)
do
    ffmpeg -i $file $(echo $file|sed 's/\.[^.]*$//').flv
done
```

Or if the subdirectories are in the same tree

```
find . -type f -name \*mov|
while read file
do
    ffmpeg -i $file $(echo $file|sed 's/\.[^.]*$//').flv
done
```

Hmmm, only saw you are on Ubuntu after writing up the windows part :-)
On windows, you can use the `for` command:

makeflv.bat:

```
setlocal
set file=%1
for %%f in (%file%) do (
  set name=%%~nf
  set directory=%%~pf
  ffmpeg -i %file% %directory%%name%.flv
)
```

Then call it for each file you want to convert, ie `makeflv test.mov`
If you have the list in a file it would be

```
for /f %f in ('type filelist.txt') do makeflv %f
```

Comment: i feel that your answer is what i want but i am very new on the bash and command lines can you please explain to me more or give me just more details on which command is the appropriate

Comment: if my subdirectories are in the same tree where should put the parent file name

Comment: the easiest is to change directories to the parent, then do the find, or do `find /parent/directory -name \*mov` etc