# ffmpeg slow down multiple audio files in a directory and put them in the same path

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch, script

I am using FFMPEG to slow down .wav files to 20% of their original speed.

The audio files are within many sub-folders and I want a bat file to slow them all down, and replace the original files with this slowed down versions.

If its not possible to replace the file being processed, creating a separate directory where the hierarchy of folders containing the processed files matches the original is also an option.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried creating my own Bat file but I'm not familiar with the syntax.
https://superuser.com/questions/296958/ffmpeg-multi-convert-videos-and-put-them-in-the-same-path?rq=1
I've been thinking about modifying the script mentioned in the answer to the question above. Would this work?

Comment: Can you show your ffmpeg command that works so we can show you how to put it in a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg does not want to overwrite the file it is currently working on, so the easiest option is output in another folder.

Here is a simple one-liner batch file (you can just paste this all in as a command and not even use a batch file):

```
for %f in (*.mp3) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -filter:a "atempo=0.5" "output\slow_%f"
```

Breaking this down, because you will need to adjust it to your specific usecase:

- `for %f in (*.mp3) do` means we want to gather up all files matching *.mp3 in the current directory, and we want to run through the following command(s) once for each file, with the variable `%f` set to the name of the particular file. Change the `*.mp3` to match the file names/types you want to process.
- `ffmpeg -i "%f"` is the beginning of the command we're running in our for loop. Every time we go around the loop, `%f` will be replaced with the name of the next file to process.
- `-filter:a "atempo=0.5"` is just an example of how you might slow down the audio. Replace this with your working filter expression.
- `"output\slow_%f"` means that, given an input file called foo.mp3, we want to make the output file named "slow_foo.mp3" in the subdirectory "output". Create the "output" directory in the same directory as all your audio files before running this.